# Querying a Django model and comparing its fields for similarities or near duplicates

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a model that records changes to other models in my database.

I would like to query for changes that only add a newline character -- `\n`.

My changes model looks like this:

```
class Change(models.Model):
    object_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        related_name="object_change_set",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    object = GenericForeignKey("object_type", "object_id")
    old_fields = models.JSONField(encoder=JSONEncoder, null=True, blank=True)  
    new_fields = models.JSONField(encoder=JSONEncoder, null=True, blank=True)
```

Essentially, I want to find instances of `Change` where the difference between a value for a key in `old_fields` and `new_fields` is `\n`.

Here's what `new_fields` look like:

```
{
    "body": "Had a great time on Wednesday.",
    "created": "2022-06-15T19:49:06.784Z",
}
```

And similarly, `old_fields`:

```
{
    "body": "Had a great time on Wednesday.\n",
    "created": "2022-06-15T19:49:06.784Z",
}
```

Note that `new_fields` and `old_fields` are both `JSONFields`.

Ultimately, I want to remove the `Change` instances that only add `\n` to the `body`.

I realize that I could do this by iterating over the queryset and looking for these discrepancies, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `__startswith` (along with an `F()` expression) and `__endswith` filters to check if the `old_fields` body starts with the `new_fields` body and ends with a :

```py
from django.db.models import F

queryset = Change.objects.filter(
    old_fields__body__startswith=F("new_fields__body"), old_fields__body__endswith="\n"
)
```

This would, however, still match if the `old_fields` body had any string between the end of the `new_fields` body and the ending line break (e.g. `"Had a great time on Wednesday.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n"`). To fix that, you can also annotate the queryset with a `Length` function and check if the `old_fields` body's length is equal to `Length("new_fields__body") + 1`:

```py
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import Length

queryset = Change.objects.annotate(old_body_len=Length("old_fields__body")).filter(
    old_fields__body__startswith=F("new_fields__body"),
    old_fields__body__endswith="\n",
    old_body_len=Length("new_fields__body") + 1,
)
```

This should work!